# Can't open application.properties in Eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, application.properties

I've encountered a problem as I'm practising with Spring Boot. I've installed in Eclipse the Spring Tool 4 plugin and then created a Spring project. The problem is I can't open the application.properties file within Eclipse and I do not understand the reason. I double click and nothing happens.

Is this a known problem or am I doing something wrong? The file is openable from outside the IDE with a text editor but it seems empty.

Thanks

Comment: What does the right-click _Open With_ menu show? Is there something in the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the file by pressing ctrl+shift+R and application. properties.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).